# Linux Bash Shell Script - To Find Files with Zero Size and Delete

Tags: files, delete, size

List of files are stored in a variable `REMOVEFILES`. Script need to verify the list of files one by one and if the file is `ZERO` in size, it should be deleted. Please help me fixing it.

```
#!/bin/bash  
REMOVEFILES=target_execution.lst,source_execution.lst;  
echo $REMOVEFILES  
for file in $(REMOVEFILES)  
do  
        echo "$file";  
        if [[ -f "$file" ]]; then  
        find $file -size 0c -delete;  
        else  
         :  
        fi  
done  

./a.sh: line 3: REMOVEFILES: command not found
```

Comment: REMOVEFILES is a list use by `for file in` so it has to be the exact syntax for it & remove the ";" too  if you really want to do that   there are no ";" ending lines in bash

Comment: Thank you. After making the changes to the script as below, it worked. Also referred - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash.              REMOVEFILES=(target_execution.lst source_execution.lst)  
echo $REMOVEFILES  
for file in ${REMOVEFILES[*]}  
do  
        echo $file;  
        if [ -f $file ]  
        then  
        find $file -size 0c -delete  
        else  
        true  
        fi  
done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `zsh`, assuming those `.lst` files contain one file path per line and are the ones you want to remove (as opposed to the `.lst` files themselves) if they are regular files of size 0:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
  
lists=(
  target_execution.lst
  source_execution.lst
)

rm -f -- ${(f)^"$(cat -- $lists)"}(N.L0)
```

With `bash`, you can always do

```
#! /bin/bash -
lists=(
  target_execution.lst
  source_execution.lst
)
to_remove=()
process() {
  [[ -f "$1" && ! -L "$1" && ! -s "$1" ]] && to_remove+=( "$1" ) 
}
for file in "${lists[@]}"; do
  readarray -c 1 -C process < "$file"
done
rm -f -- "${to_remove[@]}"
```